# How to navigate faster in react native on Android and Windows Device?

Tags: android, react-native, navigation, uwp, delay

Here is the code in index.js:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Navigator initialRoute = {{
          id: 'firstPage'
          }}
          renderScene={
              this.navigatorRenderScene
          } />

    );
  }

  navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {

      switch (route.id) {
          case 'firstPage':
            return(<FirstPage navigator={navigator} title="First Page"/>);
          case 'secondPage':
            return(<SecondPage navigator={navigator} title="Second Page"/>);
      }
  }
```

Inside firstPage.js

```
class FirstPage extends Component {
...
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.onFirstButtonPress()}>
</TouchableHighlight>


  onFirstButtonPress() {
    this.props.navigator.push({
        id:'secondPage'
    })
  }
...
}
```

Inside secondPage.js:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.onSecondButtonPress() } > </TouchableHighlight>

  onSecondButtonPress() {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  }
```

My intend here is after click FirstButton on FirstPage, I navigate to SecondPage. After clicking SecondButton, I return to FirstPage.

My code works, but when I click on FirstButton, I see the first page slowly disappears, and the 2nd page slowly shows up, and there is 1 or 2 seconds, they overlap each other. Is there a way I can make a clear and quick switch between the two?

Comment: In UWP, you can `WinJS.Navigation` to navigation to the page2, then you can [`WinJS.Navigation.back`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229802.aspx) to go back to page1.

Comment: Is that for react native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine to me. Can you check couple of things here, please :

1) You are running on Debug mode.(That boosts the performance)

2) See if you have not triggered Slow Animations in your simulator. Try clicking on Slow Animation from Debug->Slow Animation.

Comment: Thank you, do you know on Android and windows emulator, whether there is a slow animation button? I search online, didn't see one. Sorry I didn't say the platform at first. Thank you all the same!